monit states that certificate is expired but its not
I use M/Monit to monitor my servers. For a few days, this test is broken. It seems the test uses another certificate than I see in the browser.
check host cloud.example.com
  with address cloud.example.com
  group web
  if failed
    host cloud.example.com
    IPV4
    IPV6
    type TCPSSL
    protocol https
    certificate valid > 21 days
  for 3 times within 15 cycles then alert

But when I check the certificate in Firefox, it's valid until Februare 2025, Qualys SSL Check says A+ for both, IPv4 and IPv6.
Already tried to renew the certificate, that did not solve the issue but created a new certificate.
But Monit thinks the certificate has expired. I don't understand why. What exactly is being tested here?
Any Ideas?

Is monit running on the same machine as your browser? If not, have you tried retrieving the certificate from your target host on the same machine as monit, and verifying that it's the same certificate you're seeing in your browser?

The browser is of cource on another machine. Buzt when I use curl -v with the same domain as monit, it shows a valid certificate with expiration date in february.

It's an IPv6 issue.After disabling the IPv6 check, it worked.
Even if
dig cloud.example.com AAAA

returned the IPv6 address of that server, something is wrong. My knowledge of IPv6 is to limited to understand what. I need IPv6 to be able to access multiple VMs from outside having only one world-wide routed IPv4 address. This is done by a reverse proxy redirecting IP4 requests to the correct VM. IPv6 request go directly to that VM.
The VM in question is the only one available via IP4 and IP6 and hosts the reverse proxy.
I've added the IPv6 localhost address to `/etc/hosts`` what solved the issue.
127.0.0.1 localhost cloud.example.com
::1       cloud.example.com


Which means the proxy and the VM have two separate certificates for the same domain, and most likely one of them was correctly set up for auto-renewal but the other one wasn't. If removing AAAA records made things work, then your proxy has the working setup but your real server (which was being directly checked via IPv6) doesn't auto-renew.

Thats correct wohoo!
